# SharePoint REST API - Create lookup column with additional fields

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to create a lookup column using the SharePoint REST API but can't figure out a way to pull the additional columns from the source list.

I am using SP.FieldCreationInformation to do this. Code sample below. Is there any way to pull the additional columns from the source list and create them at the same time? Basically, I want to know if the REST API will allow me to use the "Select additional columns" functionality that you can utilize in the GUI? (Image below)

[image]

```
"headers": {
            "X-RequestDigest": "form digest value",
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-length": "length of body data"
        },
        "body": "{ 'parameters': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldCreationInformation' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 7,\n    'Title': 'User', 'LookupListId': '53ca895d-8f0c-40ae-ab7a-01d1b7a6dc0e',\n    'LookupFieldName': 'Title' } }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creation of your lookup field you can call another rest api as shown below to add the dependent (additional) fields.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')/fields/adddependentlookupfield(displayname='Project', primarylookupfieldid='c3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc6f', showfield='Title')",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>>,
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182%28v%3Doffice.15%29) article if you need more help. Hope it helps.